# Why is there a 2px vertical alignment difference bootstrap select and button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have wrapped a standard bootstrap select box, and button, in divs with `display: inline-block`

This makes the select box being displayed exactly 2 pixels higher than the button. I've tried to debug to find which css property makes this happen, but cannot figure it out.

The elements align if I add `vertical-align: -2px;` on the div wrapping the select. I just don't understand exactly why I need this, and why they are differently aligned in the first place. I would very much appreciate if anyone could help me better understand this.

https://jsfiddle.net/3vdjf28y/

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div id="select-container" class="inline">
      <select class="form-control" id="info-template-select">
                                                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value="-1">Select something</option>
                                                </select>
    </div>
    <div class="inline"><button class="btn btn-info" id="btn-first-next">Next</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.inline{
  display: inline-block;
}

/*
#select-container{
  vertical-align: -2px;
}

*/
```

Comment: I don't know why so much people are hype on bootstrap, it always caused me problems in projects i worked on that used it, conflicts and weird things. Setting `vertical-align: top;` to your `.inline` class should solve it.

Comment: i woul simply say that you need to follow the documentation and use form container provided by bootstrap --> http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline

Comment: @Kaddath here is https://jsfiddle.net/hdLvtLdy/3/ --> and i was precise since the link i shared is for the inline-forms ;)

Comment: Both comments here are awesome. The first explains exactly which property and which elements creates the difference in appearence, while the second comment explains how bootstrap intended us to use their code. Fantastic. Thanks. Write them up as answers, and I'll upvote them both.

Comment: @TemaniAfif that was before the edit adding the link, removed my comment afterwards

Comment: Its the border on the input. It defaults to in INSET border, confusing your margins.

Answer (score 1):

use `float: left;`

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.inline{
    float: left;
}

button{
    border: 0;
}

/*
#select-container{
  vertical-align: -2px;
}

*/
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="select-container" class="inline">
            <select class="form-control" id="info-template-select">
                <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value="-1">Select something</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="inline"><button class="btn btn-info" id="btn-first-next">Next</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if this is an issue for you, you can set a height to the 'Next' button.